# Why does node.js Buffer.slice not clone memory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If `Buffer` is supposed to extend `Uint8Array`, then why do the two following pieces of code produce different results? Does this not go against the concept of inheritance, i.e. breaking code that expects `Uint8Array` objects?

```
const a = new Uint8Array(1);
const b = a.slice();
b[0] = 1;
console.log(...a); // prints 0

const a = new Buffer(1);
const b = a.slice();
b[0] = 1;
console.log(...a); // prints 1
```

Comment: That behaviour is [documented here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarray): "Buffer instances are also Uint8Array instances. However, there are subtle incompatibilities with TypedArray. For example, while ArrayBuffer#slice() creates a copy of the slice, the implementation of Buffer#slice() creates a view over the existing Buffer without copying, making Buffer#slice() far more efficient."

Comment: I found that, too. But still, does that not mean that you can't safely use buffers in the context that expects typed arrays? Doesn't this break kind-of relationship that inheritance implies?

Comment: It doesn't explicitly state that `Buffer` inherits from `Uint8Array` in the classical OOP sense. If you want to make sure that your code functions as expected, you probably have to convert to a typed array to prevent possible issues due to those incompatibilities.